# which sounds more natural

Tags: past-simple, progressive-aspect

So I was wondering which sounds the most natural and most proper sounding statement a or b

> A: the girl was walking down the street.

or

> B: the girl walked down the street.

I just was making a book and wanted to know and yes I'm that bored xD

Comment: Would you please provide the context of this statement?

Comment: Both sentences sound natural. If you are telling a story, it's a stylistic choice. When you are telling a story to friends, you might start with, "A girl was walking down the street, and...." However, in other contexts it would be just as natural to say, "The girl walked down the street."